# Ruby on Rails - Adding a second (extremely) simple Auth layer in app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Once a user logs into their account, they are presented with a list of 'Employees'.

As of right now, when you click an employee, it takes the user to the 'show' page of that specific employee, however I want to add a 'pin-protected' aspect to that list before it renders the show page.

I want to add a simple layer of authentication that would go like this:

1. When a user clicks their name on a list, a text-field appears that asks for the selected employee's pin.
2. The user types in the pin. On submit, it compares the inputted pin against the 'pin' column for that employees' record. If it's correct it grants access to the selected employee's show page.

Is this something that is easily done in RoR? This is the first real app I have worked on, so I am having trouble wrapping my mind around a couple concepts like these.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Does the pin currently exist in your model?

Comment: Yes, well the pin is recorded in each employee's record when the employee is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise), it's most definitely your best bet for Ruby on Rails 3 authentication layer.

---

You're best bet if you just want to add a little functionality to your existing model class would be to add a method along the lines of:

```
def validate_pin(pin_to_check)
    self.pin == pin_to_check
end
```

And then you just need to modify your employee controller so that `show` method checks to see if the pin has been provided (ideally via a session variable), otherwise redirect and request the pin with an additional method and route `Employee#request_pin` in the controller which asks the user to enter the pin, on success redirecting to the `Employee#show` route.

**Session handling in the controller**

To write the session variable, you'd need an `Employee#check_pin` method  (as a POST route) and you'd  just use the code:

```
session[:pin_valid] = true
```

Then you'd check `session[:pin_valid]` in your `Employee#show` method

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation! I already have my whole user auth model set up though and working -- I am just looking to add that next simple layer, which is checking employee pins before allowing access to their view page... Does devise allow this type of thing also?

Comment: I'd have thought so, but it'll be a bit of large job for such a trivial task.

Comment: Yes! This looks great. My only other question would be how to write the form input of the users pin into a session variable. Thank you so much for your help, it has been great.

Comment: I am sorry to keep asking questions, but is there a way to actually POST data directly from a form to a session? I have searched for a couple hours and can't seem to find anything.

Comment: You'd be better off asking another question.